# Compiler showing warnings even though code is working

Tags: c, file, pointers, compiler-warnings

I've been working on this problem:

Write a program that merges lines alternately from two files and writes the results to new file. If one file has less number of lines than the other, the remaining lines from the larger file should be simply copied into the target file.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    fp=fopen("sample3.txt","r");
    fp1=fopen("sample4.txt","r");
    fp2=fopen ("output.txt","w");
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    int *p;
    int *c;
    while (1){
        if (p=fgets(a,100,fp)!=NULL){
            fputs (a,fp2);
        }
        if (c=fgets(b,100,fp1)!=NULL){
            fputs (b,fp2);
        }
        if (c==NULL && p==NULL){
            break;
        }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Though the output.txt file contains the strings from both the files, yet compiler shows
[Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast in the following two lines:

if (c=fgets(b,100,fp1)!=NULL)

and

if (p=fgets(a,100,fp)!=NULL)

Can someone help?

Comment: Warnings are exactly that, they're basically saying that this is ambiguous and/or potentially dangerous and may or may not work the way you intended. -- If you want a good answer, post the exact warning message and mark the line that it applies to in the source.

Comment: Yeah, so `fgets` returns a `char*`, so why do you declare `c` and `p` as `int*`?

Comment: Why are you using fgets at all?  This is best done with `fgetc`.  Read one character at a time.  When you see a `\n`, change the input source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
c = fgets(b, 100, fp1) != NULL
```

is equivalent to:

```
c = (fgets(b, 100, fp1) != NULL)
```

because `!=` has a higher precedence than `=`, therefore this turns the boolean integer from the comparison into a pointer. You should use explicit parentheses to fix this:

```
(c = fgets(b, 100, fp1)) != NULL
```

That will do the assignment to `c` (since the parentheses give that operation a higher precedence) *then* compare that value with `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. `p` and `c` are pointers to wrong type (`int` instead of `char`)
2. If statement is wrong. It assings the pointer with the result of the logical expression. The result of the logical expression can be `1` or `0` which are integers, thus warning. You need to assign pointer first, then compare.

```
    char *p;
    char *c;
    while (1){
        if ((p=fgets(a,100,fp))!=NULL){
            fputs (a,fp2);
        }
        if ((c=fgets(b,100,fp1))!=NULL){
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any parenthesis this you are doing this:

```c
if (c= (fgets(b,100,fp1)!=NULL) )
```

The result of comparison is `int` and that is what you are assigning to your `char* c`. You can print it and you will see that it is either `1` (when `fgets()` returns something other than `NULL`) or `0` (if `fgets()` returns `NULL`).

What you want is the following:

```c
if ( (c=fgets(b,100,fp1)!=NULL) )
```

or even better (until you are better versed in combining multiple statements)

```c
c= fgets(b,100,fp1);
if ( c!=NULL )
```

Same has to be done with the second line. Also, change `p` and `c` from `int*` to `char*`.

Comment: Your first solution does not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. allows for lines longer than 99 characters
3. checks for all I/O errors
4. reports I/O errors on `stderr`
5. performs the desired functionality
6. gives 'magic' numbers, like 100, meaningful names
7. can be easily 'tweaked' so once an EOF is encountered, that file not read anymore

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 100


int main( void )
{
    
    FILE *fp = fopen( "sample3.txt", "r" );
    if( ! fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read: sample3.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    FILE *fp1 = fopen( "sample4.txt", "r" );
    if( ! fp1 )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read: sample4.txt failed" );
        fclose( fp );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    FILE *fp2 = fopen ( "output.txt", "w" );
    if( ! fp2 )
    {
        perror( "fopen to write: output.txt failed" );
        fclose( fp );
        fclose( fp1 );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    char buffer[ MAX_LINE_LEN ];

    char *ap = NULL;
    char *bp = NULL;
    
    do
    {
        do
        {
            if ( (ap = fgets(buffer, sizeof( buffer ),fp) ) != NULL )
            {  // then read successful
                if( EOF == fputs ( buffer, fp2 ) )
                {  // then, write failed
                    perror( "fputs failed" );
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            { // else, read failed
                perror( "fgets failed" );
                break;
            }
        // while end of line not found
        } while( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL ); 
        
        do
        {
            if ( (bp = fgets(buffer, sizeof( buffer ),fp1) ) != NULL )
            {
                if( EOF == fputs ( buffer, fp2 ) )
                {
                    perror( "fputs failed" );
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                perror( "fgets failed" );
                break;
        } while( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL );
    // while more to read
    } while( ap || bp );
    
    fclose( fp );
    fclose( fp1 );
    fclose( fp2 );
    return 0;
}
```